# Trying to build a page that detects whether a user's camera avaible or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-webcam-plugin

I am very beginning of program coding. Just trying the see if user has a webcam available or not and print it in html. So far I manage to write this code below:

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.webcam.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Camera and Audio Status</h2>
  <div id="StatusList">

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#camera").webcam(
      {            
        width: 320,            
        height: 240,            
        mode: "callback",
        swffile: "/lorran/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
        onTick: function() {},
        onSave: function() {},
        onCapture: function() {},
        debug: function() {},
        onLoad: function() {}        }
    );
    var statusHTML='<ul class="bulleted">';
    var test;
    test = function()
    {
      var tester = false;            
      try
      {
        if(webcam.getCameraList().length == 0)
        {                      
          /*alert('You dont have a camera');*/
          statusHTML +='<p>camera is not avaible</p>';
          return;                
        }
        else
        {
          /*alert("cam");*/ 
          statusHTML +='<p>camera avaible</p>';
          return;
        }
        tester = true;
      }
      catch(e)
      {                
        tester = false;
        setTimeout(test,1000);
      }        
    }        
    setTimeout(test,1000);
    statusHTML +='</ul>';
    $('#StatusList').html(statusHTML);
  </script>
</body>
```

I am not able to see anything in the page or in console :( I have download and added `jquery.webcam.js`. Am I totally wrong direction?

http://lyncchecker.ucb.com/ I am trying to make something look like this.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Also your code references `$("#camera")` but I see no element in your HTML with id "camera".

Comment: Modern browsers block flash. Are you sure console has no errors? Search for html5 based solutions instead of outdated flash based ones.

Comment: @Pointy no errors in console.I added <div id="camera"> to html nothing change. Do I have to run this in mybe IIS?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the server. That webcam tool you're using is Flash based and therefore probably not your best option.